# applying theme to Yii2 advanced application

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to apply a theme to yii2 advanced application in frontend.

the code I am using to apply the theme is as follows:

```
 'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/stargazers'],
            'baseUrl' => '@web/../themes/stargazers',
        ],
    ],
```

pretty URL is turned on.

The physical location of theme is in the path like

frontend/themes/stargazers.
and stargazers folder is having this files and folders.

```
files/
layouts/
layouts/main.php
files/main_style.php
files/theme/
files/theme/main_style.css
files/theme/*.png
```

I have tried all path location, but was not able to apply the theme, may be missing something silly here.

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 advanced template does not have `@app` this namespace by default, should you change to `@frontend`?

```
'view' => [
    'theme' => [
        'pathMap' => ['@frontend/views' => '@frontend/themes/stargazers'],
        'baseUrl' => '@frontend/themes/stargazers',
    ],
],
```